# get network speed on specific interface

Tags: java, android, networking

I am trying to get the network speed on interface `tun0`. I am currently getting the network speed but I am not sure which network interface it is accessing. What is the correct way to get the network speed on a specific interface on Android using Java? Thanks in advance.

**Current method**

```js
public void networkSpeed() throws Exception {
  Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
  NetworkCapabilities nc = null;
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    nc = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActiveNetwork());
  }

  int downSpeed = nc.getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps();
  int upSpeed = nc.getLinkUpstreamBandwidthKbps();
  System.out.println("{\"downSpeed\": \"" + downSpeed + "\", \"upSpeed\": \"" + upSpeed + "\"}");
}
```